# ASA Anywhere v9 - MS SQL 2005 : Conversion Tools

Tags: sql-server, sybase, conversion

im hoping for some advice and hopefully information regarding the conversion of an ASA Anywhere v9 Database to MS SQL 2005 Standard Edition.

Basically our v9 ASA database is no longer supported by Sybase, due to the costs involved upgrading it to a supported version we have opted to move the entire system over to MS SQL 2005 Std Edition.

can anyone post feedback regardind any experiences they have had doing this or tools they have used to accomplish this sort of transfer? pitfalls, problems or anything that would be handy to know before i start?

the ASA DB is presently 7.5GB as well btw, out of interest in a perfect world where the db converts first time totally automatically, can anyone take a guess at some rough timeframes to convert a DB of this size?

im not really sure what to expect or what to plan for regading this as its the first real time we have ever opted to migrate a DB to another system, i have already done some reading and am aware of problems that may exist converting stored procedures, views etc

any help would really be appreciated on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Sybase migration utility should do the trick nicely for you.

I'm currently migrating a database (much larger than yours) and that's what I'm using for the most part.

Because of the size of the database that I'm moving it took 5 days for the initial data load.  A database that size, with a decent speed network between the servers and fast hard drives that can keep up you should be able to migrate that in just an hour or two.

What I'd recommend is do the database migration once just to see how long it takes.  Then on the day of the migration you'll know about how long you'll need to be offline for.  In the case of the migration that I'm doing now, thanks to the techniques that I'm using, we are planning on up to a 5 hour outage to do the migration.